# How can I get my word documents to stop saving to OneDrive on my Mac?

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, onedrive

I have read the help article from Microsoft, articles on here, and on the Microsoft forum, and none of them seem to apply. When they say open a word doc and go to file -> options, there is no "options" in my file tab. When they say go to OneDrive settings -> back up tab, there is no "back up tab" in my OneDrive settings. When they say go to save, click other and select your computer out of recents and then select set as default, I have basically none of those options. I'm very frustrated and don't know why my set up seems to be limited or different. I'm not very computer-savvy but this seems worse than usual. I just want my word documents to save to my desktop like they used to.

Comment: May I confirm if you only need Word stop to save to OneDrive? Please check if the methods mentioned in this article was helpful to you: [How to stop Word saving to OneDrive](https://bigtechquestion.com/2019/12/18/software/microsoft-office/stop-word-saving-to-onedrive/)

Answer (score 0):

When you read documentation about Word and see references to File > Options, they are talking about the Windows version of Word. Do a quick mental language translation for the Mac and think Word > Preferences.

[image]

From this dialog choose SAVE

[image]

If the box labeled "Turn on AutoSave ..." is checked, clear it.

Now the next time you go to save a document, if it still try's to send it to OneDrive, choose the ON MY Mac button and save your document. From then on, Word should remember your last choice and present you with a dialog for saving locally versus to OneDrive.

Hope this helps